# RoR - Dynamic body (part) in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

My goal is to retrieve the a mailer's body from db.

I created a model that store the body in db, with simple text, html tag and variable (as in the original static mailer's body) and changed the piece of body in mailer's view.

I tried with `<%= raw @body_db.html.html_safe %>` , the text is correctly imported from db, but when i receive the mail there isn't variables's substitution.

Example: 
if in DB template i have
`Cliente: <%= @nome_cliente %>`, in my mail i receive `Cliente: <%= @nome_cliente %>` but i want `Cliente: Jon Doe`

P.S. : 
All variables are ok using 'static' text

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Does the file have a .erb extension? It should be `action_name.txt.erb` `action_name.html.erb`

Comment: yes the file is action_name.html.erb, the same i used before trying to retrieve the body from DB

Comment: Ah i misread that, sorry. Only other thing I can think of is checking the instance variable names, and ensure they are set. I would think it would render an empty return if that were the case though.

Comment: Ah wait. Because it's in the db template, it will not be re-evaluated. I would recommend passing the body_db through ERB itself, and render that output. Can see how to do it here: http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/

Comment: uhm..... also rendering a template in main view I have the same result, variable in text from db are not evalutated............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great !!!

I found solution!

Without using partial, I used this in my view, so i can include ERB in DB !!

```
<%= render :inline => @body_db.html.html_safe, :layout => false %>
```

Thanks to all !